# Disable caching for IOS PWA

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, iphone, nginx, progressive-web-apps

I built a Todo App in Ruby on Rails (With a Passenger and Nginx), i used this app as a PWA with apple-mobile-web-app-capable and apple-touch-fullscreen meta tags on my iPhone (IOS 12.3.1). When I create tasks via the browser and switch back to the PWA, they are not displayed. If i close the app very often or wait a long time, they will be displayed in the PWA. I think IOS cached the Web-page. My question is how can I disable caching for the page ? I've already tried the following meta tags, they did not work. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```